# Solving a system of linear equations with Cramer's Rule

Tags: vb.net, math

currently I am trying to complete this series of linear equations using Cramer's Rule. I am not familiar with Cramer's rule either. I was able to display the equation but not solve the systems. The system equation is 3x - 4y = 15 and right below is -6x + y = -9. Note: I am not sure how to fix the Dim Body issue with this post, I apologize.

```
Dim a1 As Double, a2 As Double, b1 As Double, a3 As Double, a4 As Double, b2 As Double, D As Double, Dx As Double, Dy As Double, c1 As Double, c2 As Double, X As Double, Y As Double


        Console.WriteLine("Input the coefficients of the first equation: a11, a12, b1: ")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a1 = ")
        a1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a2 = ")
        a2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("b1 = ")
        b1 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Input the coefficients of the second equation: a21, a22, b2: ")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a3 = ")
        a3 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a4 = ")
        a4 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("b2 = ")
        b2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Output the system of equations: ")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("(" & a1 & ")x + (" & a2 & ")y = " & b1)
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("(" & a3 & ")x + (" & a4 & ")y = " & b2)
        Console.WriteLine()

        c1 = a1 + b1
        c2 = a3 + b2

        Dx = (c1 * b2) - (b1 * c2)
        Dy = (a1 * c2) - (c1 * a3)
        D = (a1 * b2) - (b1 * a3)

        X = Dx / D
        Y = Dy / D


        Console.WriteLine("Output the result: ")
        If D And Dy And Dx = 0 Then

            Console.WriteLine("Infinte Solutions! The system is inconsistent and dependent.")

        ElseIf D = 0 And Dy <> 0 And Dx <> 0 Then

            Console.WriteLine("No solutions! The system is inconsistant.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("A unique solution! The system is consistent and indepent.")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("x = " & X)
            Console.WriteLine("y = " & Y)
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
```

So for this specific equation system, I expect a 1 coming from the X value and a -3 for the Y value. Instead, I am getting X = 1, and Y = 1 which is not the answer that should be outputted. Hopefully, I was able to explain this issue with enough detail.

Comment: Can't help but feel you might be better off posting this in one of the math stacks rather than here, at best as is it's a straight debug your code question.  Since you don't really understand Cramer's rule yourself, you're probably going to struggle to explain Why it's not right.  And please turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

Ok as to what is Cramer you can read on your own.

As for the code

```vb
c1 = a1 + b1
c2 = a3 + b2
```

What is this? idk why you did it. You don't need it

Cramer is calculated det of original mat, and for each variable you need to find, you replace its column with free coefficients.

So to find original det with the mat in this form:

```
|a1 a2|b1
|a3 a4|b2
D  = a1 * a4 - a3 * a2
```

And for x?
Replace the first column with free coefficients and get

```
|b1 a2|
|b2 a4|
Dx  = b1 * a4 - b2 * a2
```

```
|a1 b1|
|a3 b2|
Dy = a1 * b2 - a3 * b1
```

So to `ctrl+c`

```
Dx = b1 * a4 - b2 * a2
Dy = a1 * b2 - a3 * b1
D  = a1 * a4 - a3 * a2
```

You confused yourself, because usually, it would be written as

```
|a1 b1|c1
|a2 b2|c2

or

|a11 a12|c1
|a21 a21|c2
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to write less code.  Separate the part that executes Cramer's Rule from the I/O interaction with the user.  The function will be reusable.

Test your function out with hardcoded values that you know the answer to.

You should know that Cramer's rule might be fine for 2x2 or 3x3 systems of equations, but it's more typical to use Gaussian elimination or LU decomposition.

You can generalize Cramer's rule using recursion, but you'd be crazy to do so.  Solving an n x n matrix using Gaussian elimination or LU decomposition is O(n^3), but recursive Cramer's rule quickly becomes O(n!).  Not good.

Here is a solution that uses Python and NumPy:

```
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829206/solving-a-system-of-linear-equations-with-cramers-rule
# see https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/advanced-algebra/cramers-rule-with-two-variables/
# see https://www.chilimath.com/lessons/advanced-algebra/cramers-rule-with-three-variables/

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from numpy.linalg import solve, det

def cramer3x3(a, b):
    assert a.shape == (3, 3)
    assert b.size == 3
    d = det(a)
    d1 = det(np.column_stack([b, a[:, 1], a[:, 2]]))
    d2 = det(np.column_stack([a[:, 0], b, a[:, 2]]))
    d3 = det(np.column_stack([a[:, 0], a[:, 1], b]))
    return np.array([d1/d, d2/d, d3/d])


def cramer2x2(a, b):
    assert a.shape == (2, 2)
    assert b.size == 2
    d = det(a)
    dx = det(np.column_stack([b, a[:, 1]]))
    dy = det(np.column_stack([a[:, 0], b]))
    return np.array([dx/d, dy/d])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('2x2 Cramer')
    a = np.array([[4., -3.],[6., 5.]])
    b = np.array([11., 7.])
    expected = pd.DataFrame(np.array([2., -1.]))
    print('Expected')
    print(expected)
    x = pd.DataFrame(solve(a, b))
    print('Solver')
    print(x)
    z = pd.DataFrame(cramer2x2(a, b))
    print('Cramer')
    print(z)

    print('3x3 Cramer')
    a = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
                  [3., 1., -3.],
                  [-3., 4., 7.]])
    b = np.array([-5., 4., -7.])
    expected = pd.DataFrame(np.array([-1., 1., -2.]))
    print('Expected')
    print(expected)
    x = pd.DataFrame(solve(a, b))
    print('Solver')
    print(x)
    z = pd.DataFrame(cramer3x3(a, b))
    print('Cramer')
    print(z)
```